# Routes on zend modules

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to make a kind of alias for my modules:
Is there a way to make

- http://www.example.com/news point to
  /modules/news/controller/news/->action
  index.
- And if i go to
  http://www.example.com/news/show it
  automaticly points to 
  /modules/news/controller/news/ ->
  action show

Or do I have to make a route for every single action I make in this module?
If I don't make a route my links will look like:

http://www.example.com/news/news/show and http://www.example.com/news/news/show.

P.s i'm using Zend 1.10.6

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it will be something like that:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
'news',
array('module' => 'news', 'controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'index'));
$router->addRoute('news', $route);
```

where first arg 'news' for Zend_Controller_Router_Route is the url http://www.example.com/news that will route to http://www.example.com/news/news/index

salu2

Comment: Thank you, but that was exactly my problem, i don't want news/news/index in my url.... i'd prever news/index. 

The only way to achive that is adding a route for every page, like Daniel explained.

Answer (score 1):

In your config file you must enable modules by putting this in your config file

```
resources.modules[] =
```

And it should by default route correctly in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define a route for each URL you want routed in a non-standard way.